# i have encountered problems in material ui implementation packages. Which package should i install for this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Failed to compile.

./src/Component/Form.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Login' in 'C:\Users

Answer (score 0):

[@mui/icons-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material)
 is an isolated package so you should install it separately

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Comment: I have tried to install @mui/icons-material but the problem remains the same

Comment: "@mui/material": "^5.0.0", in package.json. The problem remains. (my error tells me about mui/material instead of the icons package)